# Issue with my banner slider on my webpage

Tags: jquery, magento

I am trying to get my banner to run on my Magento site but it is trowing this error preventing it from running.[image]

I have seen some cases with a similar problem but can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this was answered already 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592453/jquery-cycle-is-not-a-function-error-follow-up-from-http-stackoverflow-co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i think You have multiple instances of jQuery on your page

like jquery.js ,jquery.min.js ,jquery 1.5.2.min.js check which js apply for your page for run slider

Comment: Yep I had another extension that was including its own version of jQuerry. Thanks!